# VPC router does not route traffic to CSR

Tags: amazon-web-services, cisco, routing, amazon-vpc, filtering

I am trying to configure VPC Gateway Redundancy with Cisco Cloud Services Router (CSR).
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Hybrid_Cloud/Intercloud/CSR/AWS/CSRAWS/CSRAWS_4.html

client1---VPN---CSR1--client2

It's almost working correctly: CSR devices are able to modify the APIs if one of them goes down, CSR are able to ping the devices over the VPN.
So CSR1 is able to ping both client1 and client2.
However, the issue I have is client 2 is not able to ping client1.

The VPC router has a route saying if you want to ping client1 the target is the internal interface of CSR1. However if I take a packet capture on that interface, I cannot see any traffic. 
Moreover, if I change the VPC routing table and say, ok now the target is not the CSR anymore, it is a Linux instance, then the traffic is correctly redirected.

There is no ACL on the router (I'm not even receiving the trafic regarding my packet capture), the source/dest check is disabled. I use the AX license and there is not security groups or Network ACL that could block the traffic.

I'm running out of ideas, everything is working correctly with Linux instances, but the traffic does not seem to be redirected if I use Cisco instances.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanls

Comment: Please explain more clearly what  "client1" "client2" are.  If they are both the same kind of thing, then I don't understand why one of them shows to be on the other side of a `---VPN---` but the other isn't shown that way.  Are they both VPN clients of the CSR, or what?

Comment: Client2 is an AWS instance (linux) connected to the same VLAN as CSR1 (CSR is an AWS instance too). Client1 is a physical device connected as a EzVPN client to CSR1. When client2 wants to reach client1, it redirects its traffic to its default gateway, that is to say the VPC router, however the VPC router does not route the traffic to the CSR, even with an acitve route within its routing table